# INSERT запрос к таблице с foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

Не совсем понимаю, что писать в поле VALUE(команды INSERT) для столбца имеющего свойство foreign key, можете простой пример привести?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FOREIGN KEY - это ограничение, в поле можно ввести только значения содержащиеся в базовой таблице, либо NULL, если определение поля такое позволяет.

Answer (score 0):

Ну FOREIGN KEY, это действительно ограничение - связь с другой таблицей (таблицей-родителем). Соответственно, в данном столбце можно указывать только существующие значения PRIMARY KEY родительской таблицы, либо NULL (если нет ограничений на NULL для данного поля). Почитай [тут](http://www.sql.ru/docs/sql/u_sql/ch19.shtml)...

Comment: а. Это не связь (с точки зрения SQL понятие связь вообще сомнительна, так как никакой сущности под собой не содержит) б. ограничивать можно не только по РК (вы можете это посмотреть как в данной вами ссылке, так и [здесь](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/SEC451.html) ).